# Why does this before hook make this test suite block forever?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, automated-tests

This JavaScript test suite works:

```js
import assert from 'node:assert/strict';
import http from 'node:http';
import test from 'node:test';

test.describe(() => {
  const server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
    response.statusCode = 200;
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    response.setHeader('Content-Length', '12');
    response.end('hello, world');
  });
  server.listen(8000, 'localhost');

  test.after(() => {
    server.closeIdleConnections();
    server.close();
  });

  test.test(async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/');
    assert.equal(response.status, 200);
    assert.equal(response.headers.get('Content-Type'), 'text/plain');
    assert.equal(response.headers.get('Content-Length'), '12');
    assert.equal(await response.text(), 'hello, world');
  });
});
```

But if I move the `listen()` call into a hook running before the test suite with the [`test.before`](https://nodejs.org/api/test.html#beforefn-options) function, the test suite blocks forever:

```js
import assert from 'node:assert/strict';
import http from 'node:http';
import test from 'node:test';

test.describe(() => {
  const server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
    response.statusCode = 200;
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    response.setHeader('Content-Length', '12');
    response.end('hello, world');
  });

  test.before(() => {
    server.listen(8000, 'localhost');
  });

  test.after(() => {
    server.closeIdleConnections();
    server.close();
  });

  test.test(async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/');
    assert.equal(response.status, 200);
    assert.equal(response.headers.get('Content-Type'), 'text/plain');
    assert.equal(response.headers.get('Content-Length'), '12');
    assert.equal(await response.text(), 'hello, world');
  });
});
```

Why?